# Geocomplete with geocoder not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder, geocomplete

I am trying to use geocomplete but its not working:
I am using geocomplete_rails gem and geocoder rails gem.

I am new to jquery so please help me.
I followed following steps:
1. Added in gemfile

```
gem 'geocoder'  
gem 'geocomplete_rails'
```

2. my form partial view

   ### prohibited this location from being saved:

   ```
     <ul>
     <% @location.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
       <li><%= message %></li>
     <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
   ```

   ```
   $('#address').geocomplete();
   ```

Also in application.html.erb i have included following lines

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm a newbie in JavaScript So I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help you to complete what you are looking for, there are some examples about geocomplete and you can combine `gem 'geocoder'`

http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/